# Android: Best practice for creating, storing, and showing rpg-like items

Tags: android, arrays, variables, items

I need an alternative way to handle in-game items. Currently, I'm using a variable for every aspect an item could have.

Example: a weapon has damage and critical hit chance. Suppose there are two types of weapons possible, axes and swords.

```
String weapon = "Axe";
int damage = 1;
int critical = 5;
```

Now I need to add special elements, such as stat buffs(increase attack, health, spell power, etc.).

Do I need a variable for each stat a weapon could increase? Or rather a variable with the stat to be increased and a variable for the amount it is increased by? Then, have an if statement check for the stat to increase? And the same for displaying it?

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but you could have a list (or enum) of modifiers (health, power, etc), and store for each item a map of modifiers and amounts (which could also be negative, as in penalties for using the item).

And you really should use classes for defining the items, instead of individual variables:

```
class Item {
    String name;
}

class Weapon extends Item {
    int damage;
    int critical;
}
```

... and so on.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how your code works. I think each item will have a maximum of 3 out of 4 types of stat increases. When the player receives a new item, a new activity will open and randomly generate the item. If the player decides to take the item, it will be saved in one of 3 arrays(the first open or replaced)